# Having trouble parsing text files and finding matches in separate logs

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

I have two text files that I am trying to parse. What I want to do is find a specific keyword in one log, and see if the next log has the same keyword.

The logs have lines that consist of tag-value pairs that look like this: LOG 1 has more lines than LOG 2

```
log 1
32=A 9=value 39=value2 10=value3xyz D=339 Z=abcdef
32=A 100=value 10=randomvalue 109=randomvalue2 376=435014 528=A

log 2
9=value 39=value2 22=value3xyz D=339 Z=abcdef
100=value 22=blahblah 109=randomvalue2 376=435014 528=A
```

There are about 20,000 lines that look similar to this.

Essentially what I am trying to do is find the values for all the "11=" tags in log 1, like value3xyz and randomvalue, and then search log 2 and see if the tag "22=" has any of the values that tag 11 had.

I want to be able to print something like this

```
Log 1:
Line: 9=value 39=value2 10=value3xyz D=339 Z=abcdef
Log 2:
Line: 9=value3 39=value12 22=value3xyz D=3349 Z=abcdefda

Log 1:
Line: 100=value 10=randomvalue 109=randomvalue2 376=435014 528=A
Log 2:
Not found
```

Here is what I have:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileData {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                FileInputStream log1Stream = new FileInputStream("src/txtfiles/log1.txt");
                FileInputStream log2Stream = new FileInputStream("src/txtfiles/log2.txt");
                BufferedReader log1Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(log1Stream));
                BufferedReader log2Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(log2Stream));
                ArrayList<String> parentTagValue = new ArrayList<String>();    
                ArrayList<String> childTagValue = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> hasChild = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> noChild = new ArrayList<String>();

                String upstream;
                String downstream;
                String strLine;

                // put all of the "10=" tag values into an arraylist
                while ((strLine = log1Reader.readLine()) != null)   {

                  if (strLine.contains("32=A")) {
                        parentTagValue.add((strLine.substring(strLine.lastIndexOf(" 10=") + 4).replaceAll(" .+$", "")));
                  }

                }

               // put all of the "22=" tag values into an arraylist
                while ((strLine = log2Reader.readLine()) != null)   {

                        if (strLine.contains("22=")) {
                                childTagValue.add(strLine.substring(strLine.lastIndexOf(" 22=") + 4).replaceAll(" .+$", ""));
                        }
                }

                // see which "10=" tag values have a "child value" in log 2
                for (String string : parentTagValue) {
                        if (childTagValue.contains(string)) {
                                hasChild.add(string);
                        }
                        else {
                                noChild.add(string);
                        }
                }



                log1Reader.close();
                log2Reader.close();
                System.out.println(noChild.size()+hasChild.size());
        }
}
```

I am not sure how I can print out the lines from the logs to show the information that I want to show above. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Also, is there better/more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Are you certain that both files have the same number of lines, and that no data is missing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, the logs don't necessarily have the same amount of lines. There's about 15-20k lines in each log so I just kinda posted a sample of what a couple lines would look like

Comment: How do you propose to pair lines from one file against lines from the other in a meaningful (and ideally reproducible) way?